# Can one use the Drive SDK to programmatically @mention other users in document comments?

Tags: google-drive-api

Google Apps support @mentions through the application.
Is there a way to programmatically do @mentions using the Drive SDK API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API to add comments that include @mentions. You can actually use the "+EMAIL_ADDRESS" syntax or the "@EMAIL_ADDRESS" syntax in the content field of a comment created with the API and it will be treated as a mention.