# How can one make API calls to https://docs.google.com/c/u/0/data/contactstore?

Tags: google-drive-api

Follow up question to:

[Can one use the Drive SDK to programmatically @mention other users in document comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714818/can-one-use-the-drive-sdk-to-programmatically-mention-other-users-in-document-c)

I am trying to implement @mentions in our own application's comments that is on par with Google provided apps.

While the comments API supports tagging by email as mentioned in the question above, Google Apps have an extra layer of polish where they query the an undocumented API at  https://docs.google.com/c/u/0/data/contactstore for autocompleting user names for tagging purposes.

Is it possible for applications to also make calls to this API to get implement a high quality comments implementation similar to Google Apps assuming you are authenticated and have an access token? If so, how does one pass in the access token to make this call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, that API (and all other "undocumented" APIs) are not for use by 3rd parties. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would be the best way to do the equivalent if we want our own app to have comments/@mentions support that is on par with first party apps?

Comment: Use the Contacts API, or some of the G+ APIs, or for domains, use some of the Admin APIs